# Git merge to all branches

Tags: git, git-svn, git-branch

I have branches

```
v1.0
v1.1
v1.2
v1.3
v1.4 [master]
```

now i checkout the v1.0 and add some directory with files (db tables, stored procedures, etc)

how to merge the newly added directory with files in all branches so my head branch will be updated with that directory

Comment: You likely wouldn't want to merge in this case; If you did, all of your branches would be the same. You'd probably want to cherry-pick the commit that introduces the change into each branch.

Comment: @meagar Yes I agree, he needs `git cherry-pick` not `git merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need just that particular directory and no other changes which were introduced in different branches, if that is the case then, one way which comes to my mind right now is `git cherry-pick`.

Just check `git log` and find out the commit id responsible for adding that new directory and everything else you need. Now checkout your other branches one by one and use

`git cherry-pick <commid id>`

And that particular commit will be applied to that respective branch.

Comment: yeah it works but when i view it in gitk, i lost all branches except the checkout one

Comment: You did not lose all the branches, `gitk` by default only shows the branch you are currently on. To view your branches use `git branch`. To view all branches with gitk use `gitk --all`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manually merge the updated branch to rest of the branches. Just commit the directory and other files on one of the branches (say you made the commit on `v1.0`)

To merge a branch (`v.10 to v1.1`) you can do

Assume you are on v1.0 branch,

```
git checkout v1.1
git merge v1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you are on branch 1.4)
git push origin 1.4

git checkout 1.3
git pull --rebase origin
git merge 1.4

Resolve conflicts
git add conflicted-file

git commit

git push origin 1.3

Repeat this for all other branches.

Comment: After almost 100 answers, you should learn to format your code.